# Pandas dataframe rolling difference in value for 5 second intervals per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, window-functions

I have a Pandas dataframe containing timestamp (unevenly spaced), sequence number, category and percent formation. Sequence number is used only to order rows if multiple rows exist with same timestamp and category, and is dropped after sorting.

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|                        | seq_no   | category   | pct_formation |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|ts_timestamp            |          |            |               |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|2018-10-22 10:13:44.043 | 6839262  | in_petr    | 37.070000     |
|2018-10-22 10:17:09.527 | 7257908  | in_petr    | 36.970000     |
|2018-10-22 10:17:43.977 | 7319000  | in_dsh     | 36.950000     |
|2018-10-22 10:17:43.963 | 7318885  | in_dsh     | 36.960000     |
|2018-10-22 10:17:09.527 | 7257918  | in_petr    | 32.960000     |
|2018-10-22 10:19:44.040 | 7585354  | out_petr   | 36.890000     |
|2018-10-22 10:19:44.043 | 7585461  | out_petr   | 36.900000     |
|2018-10-22 10:19:37.267 | 7563817  | sync       | 33.910000     |
|2018-10-22 10:19:44.057 | 7586045  | sync       | 36.960000     |
|2018-10-22 10:19:16.750 | 7516841  | out_petr   | 36.880000     |
|2018-10-22 10:20:03.160 | 7637889  | sync       | 36.980000     |
|2018-10-22 10:20:32.350 | 7691592  | sync       | 37.000000     |
|2018-10-22 10:23:03.150 | 8008804  | sync       | 34.580000     |
|2018-10-22 10:22:18.633 | 7907782  | in_dsh     | 36.980000     |
|2018-10-22 10:25:39.557 | 8290932  | in_dsh     | 36.970000     |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want to get change in pct_formation for each category every five seconds between 10:00:00 and 11:00:00 each day.

So far, I have tried:

```
df.sort_index()[['category', 'pct_formation']] \
.groupby(['category', df.index.date])
.rolling('5s').pct_formation.mean()
```

I use group by on date because I suspect if I use timestamp as is then grouping results won't make much sense as timestamp is unevenly spaced and very granular.

How can I get evenly spaced 5-second windows between 10:00:00 and 11:00:00 (example: 10:00:00 to 10:00:05, 10:00:01 to 10:00:06, and so on). And, how do I get the difference in pct_formation between the start and end of each 5 second window?

If I use functions like min() and max() after rolling(), I get some errors like:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'out_petr'
TypeError: cannot handle this type -> object
```

Please guide me on how to proceed, I'd be very grateful. TIA.

EDIT: Adding details based on feedback in comments.

I want a rolling window, so the next window after 10:00:00 to 10:00:05 would be 10:00:01 to 10:00:06, followed by 10:00:02 to 10:00:07, and so on.

I would like to see how much the pct_formation value has changed from one window to another, so if there are multiple values in the same interval, I will use `mean()`.

I think I will have to use `.resample()` to get evenly spaced intervals between 10am and 11am everyday, but I am finding it very difficult to understand how.

I realized I can create regularly spaced time windows like:

```
pd.date_range(start=df.index.min().replace(hour=10, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0),
              end=df.index.max().replace(hour=11, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0),
              freq='5S')
```

However, I do not know how to change my dataframe to conform to these times for each category.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - do you want 5 second windows 10:00:05 to 10:00:10 to 10:00:15 etc, how does 10:00:01 to 10:00:06 fit into that? Those are two different 5 second intervals. What do you do if you have two times within the same window and category? average them? What do you do if you don't have data in a 5 second window for a category?

Comment: @flyingmeatball I want a rolling window, so the next window after 10:00:00 to 10:00:05 would be 10:00:01 to 10:00:06.. I would like to see how much the pct_formation value has changed from one window to another, so average would be good. I will edit the details into the question. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can use `resample()` and `rolling()`:

```
df['ts_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

resampled = df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates('ts_timestamp').set_index('ts_timestamp').resample('1S').ffill())

resampled['pct_formation'].rolling(5).apply(lambda x: x[0]-x[-1], raw=True)
```

Yields (a short sample):

```
category  ts_timestamp       
in_dsh    2018-10-22 10:17:43    NaN
          2018-10-22 10:17:44    NaN
          2018-10-22 10:17:45    NaN
          2018-10-22 10:17:46    NaN
          2018-10-22 10:17:47    NaN
          2018-10-22 10:17:48    0.0
          2018-10-22 10:17:49    0.0
          2018-10-22 10:17:50    0.0
          2018-10-22 10:17:51    0.0
          2018-10-22 10:17:52    0.0
          2018-10-22 10:17:53    0.0
          2018-10-22 10:17:54    0.0
          2018-10-22 10:17:55    0.0
...
```

For the time being, I am simply using `ffill()` to fill in the relatively sparse data, but you could also think about interpolating, etc.

Comment: This works, but does not give the windows between 10am and 11am. Only gives windows where the category has timestamps.. Is there anyway that can be fixed?

Comment: Is there a reason you want each category to have 3600 rows that will mostly be 0's, as they are informed by only 3 points in some cases? Seems like an odd approach, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I want to measure and compare average change in pct_formation across category for the same time periods during the days. What would be the better way to do it?

Comment: You should really include your desired output in your question.